# how to fit a gaussian to the data points in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am doing k means on data points and want to fit data points into Gaussian to help me form 
clusters.i have tried to some but not able to do. may someone tell me how to fit Gaussian in Matlab???

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fit a Gaussian to any data, you must keep in mind that
a Gussian is simply   f(x) =f_0 exp( - (x-x0)^2 /a ). Take Log_e of your data and fit a parabola! This is possible because,
log [ f(x) ]=  log f_0   - (x-x0)^2 /a